# WPF: integrate DescritionViewer beside GroupBox header

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

DescriptionViewer controls can easily be placed beside controls such as buttons without issue.  However, I've not found a way to integrate a DescriptionViewer either to the left or right of a GroupBox header (see below) such that the DescriptionViewer will retain its relative (margin) position if the GroupBox location moves as neighboring controls collapse/expand.

To reiterate, if the GroupBox location changes then, currently, the DescriptionViewer control beside it does not maintain its relative position beside the GroupBox header; it might end up many pixels away.

Example 1

[image]

Example 2

[image]

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are asking? Also, instead of links, you can upload the images so they will appear in the post.

Comment: @HockeyJ  I added the images as directed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106053/how-do-i-display-image-in-a-post-on-stack-overflow -- is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have edited the post to show you what I mean. You might have uploaded a link, rather than the images, I'm not sure. Still, please could you clearly state the question in order to help get an answer?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the `DescriptionViewer` you are using. The built-in one is Silverlight only, but the question is tagged WPF. Are you using a 3rd party control with an identical name?

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer:  DescriptionViewer is available in WPF via System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input:

xmlns:di="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input"

which you can then use per normal in XAML:

<di:DescriptionViewer ... />